# Trigger that runs when certain tuples are updated

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to make a trigger that updates or concatenates a variable when EquipmentStatKey changes from something to a set value, and changes a value when both EquipmentStatKey and UserDef2 changes.

I am very new to SQL and am not sure what I am doing wrong. The error codes it gave me are SQL80001 and SQL46010, but I think there are probably a few more syntax/logic errors.

```
GO

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER equipStatTrig
AFTER UPDATE OF EquipmentStatKey ON dbo.Equipment
FOR EACH ROW

AS

DECLARE @statVar INT, @departmentVar INT, @receiveDateVar NVARCHAR (30), @shipDateVar NVARCHAR (30), @rentDateVar NVARCHAR (30), @sellDateVar NVARCHAR (30), @notesVar NTEXT

SELECT @statVar = EquipmentStatKey
SELECT @departmentVar = DeptOwnerKey
SELECT @receiveDateVar = UserDef1
SELECT @shipDateVar = UserDef2
SELECT @rentDateVar = UserDef3
SELECT @sellDateVar = UserDef6
SELECT @notesVar = Notes

/* execute if EquipmentStatKey changed from something to 6, 1, 8, or 32 */
IF @statVar = 06 OR @statVar = 01 OR @statVar = 08 OR @statVar = 32
    BEGIN
            /*should read as "[previous note] [status] [department] [date]" */
            SET @notesVar += ' ' + @statVar + ' ' + @departmentVar + ' ' + CurrentDate
            SELECT LEN(@notesVar) AS Notes
    END
/* execute if EquipmentStatKey changed from something to 3 or 2 */
ELSE IF @statVar = 03 OR @statVar = 02
    BEGIN
            SET @shipDateVar = NULL
    END
/* execute if EquipmentStatKey changed from something to 6 */
ELSE IF @statVar = 06
    BEGIN
            SET @shipDateVar = CurrentDate
            SET @sellDateVar = CurrentDate
    END
/* execute if EquipmentStatKey changed from something to 8 or 1, && UserDef2 changed */
ELSE IF @statVar = 08 OR @statVar = 01 AND :OLD.UserDef2 != :NEW.UserDef2
    BEGIN
        SET @rentDateVar = @shipDateVar
    END
GO
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Joshua Gregory .  Are you using SQL-Server?  Did you intend to tag that rather than [windows-server-2016]?  Having accurate tags helps the most experienced users in those topics find your question.

Comment: It was definitely suppose to be in SQL-server, but I may have accidentally referenced some oracle when I was making it... Yes I know, total rookie move. :(

Comment: SQL Server does not support ROW TRIGGERS (for each row), only STATEMENT TRIGGERS.  Your trigger needs to handle multiple rows in the INSERTED and DELTED virtual tables.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming dbo.Equipment has a primary key of PK, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.triggers
    WHERE name = 'equipStatTrig'
)
BEGIN
    EXEC('DROP TRIGGER dbo.equipStatTrig')
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.equipStatTrig On dbo.Equipment
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE realTable
    SET lastEquipmentStatKeyChangeDate = GETUTCDATE()
    FROM 
        dbo.Equipment realTable
        JOIN inserted ins
            ON ins.PK = realTable.PK
            AND ins.EquipmentStatKey <> realTable.EquipmentStatKey
END
GO
```

You may need a way to handle EquipmentStatKey of NULL since `EquipmentStatKey <> NULL` will return not true unless `ANSI_NULLS` is OFF.